# Django: How can I add/delete fields in sqlite3 database?

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I've started learning Django from a YouTube course.

In the models.py file, there are two classes.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist


class Song(models.Model):
     album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     genre = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

I added the **genre** in the **Song** after the **migration**. That's why I'm having problem while adding data.
In the interactive shell, if I try to save() , it shows there's no 'genre' field. If I try to migrate again, it shows something like this:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'genre' to song without a
>   default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate
>   existing rows). Please select a fix:
>
> 1) Provide a one-off default now
>   (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
>
> 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py Select an option:

What's the proper way of adding or deleting fields?

Comment: just choose 1. and input default value for exists records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `default=""` to genere field

```
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

As the error message shows, you add a field `genre` to `Song` model without adding `default=""` nor `null=True` parameters to it. When you migrate it, django don't know how to deal with the old data that has been inserted into the database without genere field. So you should set them to null with `null=True` or other default value with `default=""`.

You can also just keep your code. But when you use the migrate command, you should tell django that you will give a default value like the django recommanded:

> 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)

press `1` and `enter` key. input `""` and then django will set all the old data `genre=""`.

Comment: To expand on this, your first priority is to migrate successfully in order to have a working application. Then, you can edit each record and input the appropriate `genre` value.

Comment: I did as per you said. Now it shows: genre added to Song . But there's still a problem. If I add some data in the interactive shell and save it, it shows django.db.utils.OperationalError: table music_song has no column named genre

Comment: As the error message shows, you don't have column named genre in you music_song table. Did you run the command `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes I did. And after that this text appeared: genre field added to Song

Comment: If it shows the genre field has been added to the Song table, It should be ok to create some data. I need more information to find the error.

Comment: Problem Solved! I migrated again and now it's working perfectly for some weird reason. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Finally I've got it. I had to put two commands: `python manage.py makemigrations music` and `python manage.py migrate`  .I forgot that. Now it's fine.